# Xcode 7 issue when showing tooltips, can tooltips be disabled altogether?

Tags: xcode

Xcode 7 gets stuck sometimes when I hover the mouse pointer on a control in the the user interface, when I look at the Activity Monitor it shows Xcode with 98% of CPU usage, then it gets back to normal operation after about a minute when the tooltip finally is shown, although most of the time I have to force Xcode to quit, as if there were multiple tooltips queued in a row.

Is there a way to disable the tooltips altogether?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I wish Apple would just fix Xcode.

Comment: @CoBrA2168 - Apple don't give a damn to developers.

Comment: This is happening to me too Im using XCode 7.2.1 and Yosemite. It sucks. I tried to contact @AppleSupport on twitter. I'll get back here if they reply something.